# Picking parent controller of AD forest

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Let's say I am a user of some organization. My canonical name is ALPHA/person1. I connect to the top level domain controller OMEGA, because I do not know correct ALPHA's host name. Is there a way to ask OMEGA for ALPHA host name? Could I ask it without binding to it? Eventually my point is to fetch person1 attributes that held by ALPHA DC.

Answer (score 0):

After some research... DOMAIN part in DOMAIN/person1 pair is a NetBIOS name stored in **flatName** attribute in CN=System. If there is no entry for our DOMAIN - traverse up to root. Check **rootDomainNamingContext** attribute of rootDSE to obtain root DC naming context. Then redo search in CN=System to find CN equal to our rootDomainNamingContext. **name** attribute in found tree it is a hostname we looking for... Repeat untill your NetBIOS name is found. Anonymous bind isn't allowed to search over CN=System in my case, but it's all depends on a DC security policies.

Comment: You can connect to a global catalog using GC:// instead of LDAP:// which stores partial replica of all users of all domains in the entire forest. Usually, every domain in forest has at least one global catalog